# define LOCAL_SRC_FILES in ndk{} DSL

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to know whether it is possible to define LOCAL_SRC_FILES in gradle.build ndk {} block.

I am currently using:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
```

in my top level gradle.build file.

My jni module gradle.build file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 11
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    def jniSrc = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/srcs/jni"

    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "core"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
            cFlags "-std=c++11"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            jni.srcDirs = ["${jniSrc}"]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        mips {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "mips"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I am asking is that under my jni sources there is code targeting different platforms, not just Android, but also iOS and WinRT.

I am a bit reluctant to migrate to experimental 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0' but if the aforementioned module solves the problem I could give it a try.

I also wouldn't like to use:

```
jni.srcDirs = []
```

and override the creation of Android.mk and thus use my own custom one, given that I am not sure if I could debug C++ natively from Android Studio thereafter (I could be wrong here though, I am definitely not an expert user of Android Studios ndk plugin).

Many thanks in advance,

Manos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With experimental plugin 0.4.0, it is possible to exclude files from NDK build by pattern, e.g.

```
android.sources {
    main {
       jni.source {
            srcDirs = ["~/srcs/jni"]
            exclude "**/win.cpp"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Paul Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766790/sparkynz)!

**P.S.** (thanks to [*rajveer*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544095/rajveer)): don't miss `Build/Clean` after you change `exclude`!

### Old answer

Unfortunately this is not supported by current gradle plugins. Even the *"experimental"* plugin only allows to add directories. I recommend to keep the traditional **Android.mk** which does this job reliably.

I also recommend not to set `jni.srcDirs = []`, but rather keep `${jniSrc}` to let Android Studio display these files for easy access and syntax highlight. If you set **`cppFlags`** and **`cFlags`** correctly, you will have full power of cross referencing through headers, too.

The trick is to disable the regular NDK build tasks, and inject a `buildNative` task instead:

```
def ndkBuild = android.ndkDirectory
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    ndkBuild += '.cmd'
}

task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine '$ndkBuild', 'NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$jniSrc/..'
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    commandLine '$ndkBuild', 'clean', 'NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$jniSrc/..'
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}

tasks.all {
    task -> if (task.name.contains('compileDebugNdk') || task.name.contains('compileReleaseNdk')) task.enabled = false
}
```

Similar approach work for **`'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'`**, but task matching is different:

```
tasks.all {
    task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('compile') && task.name.contains('MainC')) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
        if (task.name.startsWith('link')) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
        if (task.name.endsWith("SharedLibrary") ) {
            task.dependsOn buildNative
        }
}
```

### UPDATE

**buildNative** does not produce a debuggable setup. Specifically, when running **Android Native** debug configuration, Android Studio complains that it *Could not locate folder containing object files with symbols within module app*.

I suggest the following workaround, which I only tested in scenario when the native sources are split in (at least) two directories: the Android-specific files (I will call them *JNI bridge*) are in a separate directory, and the rest are elsewhere. The workaround involves building a static library with **ndk-build** and linking it with the minimal set of objects that will pull all necessary symbols from that library.

For simplicity, let us assume that the Android-specific files (**Application.mk**, **Android.mk**, and "android-jni.cpp" are in the directory `~/srcs/jni`, while the platform-independent files are in `~/srcs` and its other subdirectories.

Here is the relevant fragment of **build.gradle**:

```
def LOCAL_MODULE = "staticLib"
def appAbi = "armeabi-v7a"
def ndkOut = "build/intermediates/$LOCAL_MODULE"
def staticLibPath = "$ndkOut/local/$appAbi/lib${LOCAL_MODULE}.a"
task buildStaticLib(type: Exec, description: 'Compile Static lib via NDK') {
    commandLine "$ndkBuild", "$staticLibPath", "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=~/srcs", "NDK_OUT=$ndkOut", "APP_ABI=$appAbi", "APP_STL=gnustl_static"
}

tasks.all {
    task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('link')) {
            task.dependsOn buildStaticLib
        }
}

model {
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
        abiFilters += "$appAbi".toString()
        ldFlags += "$staticLib".toString()
        ldLibs += "log"
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
    }

    android.sources {
        main.jni.source {
            srcDirs = ["~/srcs/jni"]
        }
}
}
```

The **~/srcs/Android.mk** file may look like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/..

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := staticLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJni.cpp

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

It is important for **`LOCAL_MODULE`** in **Android.mk** to fit the name you use for **`LOCAL_MODULE`** in **build.gradle**.

### UPDATE 2

It may still be possible, thanks to *[jforce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5415159/jforce)*, see "[Link individual native source file to Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976224/link-individual-native-source-file-to-android-studio-project)"!

Comment: Hi Alex, many thanks for the reply. If I use this approach will I be able to debug C++ from Android Studio?

Comment: Unfortunately, this straightforward approach fails to launch native debug (symbol information is not available). But with just one more step of complication, native debugging can be achieved. I will post an update as soon as I have a clean setup.

Comment: @Pankaj: be careful with the DSL: I got message `could not find property "android"` when I tried to write **model.android.sources {…}** instead of **model { android.sources {…} }**

Comment: @Alex Cohn: did you do anything else to get the exclude tag to work, and which platform was this on? I don't seem to be able to get it to work on either Windows or OSX; I've tried relative and absolute paths, patterns with a specific file, directories e.t.c. I'm using experimental plugin 0.4.0.

Comment: @Rajveer: I saw it working both on Mac and on Windows with 0.3.0. I am not using this feature in my current project, so I don't know much about its behavior.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Hmm, I wonder if something has changed between 0.3.0 and 0.4.0 then. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @Rajveer: with AS 1.5.1, experimental 0.4.0, and `buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"`` on Mac. **exclude M*.cpp** does work for me.

Comment: @AlexCohn: This is so strange, I just can't get it to work. I've tried with the same settings (AS 1.5.1, exp 0.4.0, buildToolsversion 23.0.2). I've built a test project by importing the native activity sample, could you do me a huge favour and see if the files in the exclude directory are excluded? It would be a big help! https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmthmeez1vgcm1k/nativeactivity.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Rajveer: it works for me like charm. Now, maybe you miss the point of *works like charm*: AS still shows and lets me edit the excluded file, but does not compile it to `app/build/intermediates/objectFiles/armeabi-v7aDebugArm7Native-activitySharedLibrary/native-activityMainCpp/dw4leoehkvku3fcud7ljazweo`. Furthermore, if `source_file_1.o` is stuck there from the previous build, the linker fails. **Build/Clean Project** cures this.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I thought that the files might be included in the editor even if not compiled and was still not getting the correct behaviour, however I've just checked and it was because I thought that Rebuilt Project would perform a Clean first. Cleaning first then Making/Rebuilding works as you say. I've never used an IDE before that doesn't perform a Clean as part of the Rebuild...either way, thank you for testing!

Comment: That's strange. Yours truly and some other people believed that in Android Studio Clean and Rebuild [are synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083706/difference-between-clean-project-and-rebuild-project-in-android-studio#comment55248345_24083753).