# Android Studio opencv C++ compile link libraries error at runtime

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 with Gradle 2.6 experimental with NDK.

This is my error:

```
dlopen("/data/app/face.rt.jeanc.facert-2/lib/arm/libFace.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app/face.rt.jeanc.facert-2/lib/arm/libFace.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
```

Also, my lib Face should appears as libFace.so in my folders (armabi, armabi-v7, etc) but doesn't appear (compile ?)

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "face.rt.jeanc.facert"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0.1"
        }

    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }

    android.ndk { // keeping it to make AS correctly support C++ code editing and debugging
        moduleName = "Face"
        ldLibs += ['log']
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
        cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
        cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/prebuilts/include")}".toString()
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/Android-dev/SDKs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString()
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/Android-dev/SDKs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv")}".toString()
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/Android-dev/SDKs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2")}".toString()
        ldLibs += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"]// , "ibopencv_core"

        stl = "gnustl_shared" //"stlport_static"
    }


    android.productFlavors {
    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
    create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\" //"-L" +

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"

            }
        }
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\" //"-L" +

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"

            }
        }

        create("x86") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "x86"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\x86\\" //"-L" +

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"
            }
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "mips"
            }
        }
        create("fat") {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
}
```

This is part of my code that "should" load the different libraries:

```
////// JNI C++
static {System.loadLibrary("Face");}

//Externals C++ Libraries
static {System.loadLibrary("libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_contrib.a");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_core.a");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_highgui.a");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_imgproc.a");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_info.so");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_java.so");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_legacy.a");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_ml.a");}
static {System.loadLibrary("libopencv_ts.a");}
```

I'm kinda stuck for now and need some help.

EDIT: In this version of Android studio and the experimental plugin I don't have Android.Mk file to compile jni c++. So I was wondering if now it does it by itself or I have to compile manually ?

If manually how do I do that since I don't have Android.Mk ?

Answer (score 0):

Your build does succeed, but you don't copy the shared libs from OpenCV to libs directory of your app. Follow the advice in [How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool)

Note that it is possible to combine full power of Android.mk with the *experimental* plugin: see [define LOCAL_SRC_FILES in ndk{} DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636150/define-local-src-files-in-ndk-dsl).

Comment: I did everything in the first thread you sent and second one, it's still not working.

Comment: Not working - like what? What is your Android.mk doing?

Comment: When I try to compile I get this: [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: Face <= Face.cpp
In file included from jni/Face.cpp:2:0:
jni/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
 #include <algorithm>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: For OpenCV 3.0 you need `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8 APP_STL=gnustl_static`. Are these defined in `Application.mk` or on **ndk-build** ocmmand line?

Comment: Actually I'm using OpenCV 2.4.11 for Android not the version 3.0 but both of those variables has been set already in my new Application.mk (since I didn't have one before)

Comment: have you checked that this `Application.mk` is loaded by **ndk-build**?