# Android Studio 14 Native Development + CrystaX NDK

Tags: android, c++11, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to migrate a huge crossplatform C++11 (iOS+Android) app project into Android Studio 14. I am using CrystaX NDK for boost and C++14. There's an official Android Studio + CrystaX tutorial on their website's blog [here](https://www.crystax.net/en/blog/3) but it's outdated.

I've downloaded the official hello-jni example that is meant to work with Android Studio 1.4 and tried to adapt it to work with CrystaX NDK. These are my Gradle 2.5 settings:

**project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.tableair.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 4
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    /*
     * native build settings
     */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "tableair-framework"
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
        cppFlags += "-Werror"
        ldLibs = ["android", "log", "GLESv2", "crystax"]
        stl = "gnustl_static"
        /*
         * Other ndk flags configurable here are
         * cppFlags += "-fno-rtti"
         * cppFlags += "-fno-exceptions"
         * ldLibs    = ["android", "log"]
         * stl       = "system"
         */
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}
```

**local.properties**

```
ndk.dir=/Users/vilius/Software/Android/crystax-ndk-10.2.1
sdk.dir=/Users/vilius/Library/Android/sdk
```

When I try to run the app. I get this error:

```
....
:app:generateAllDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:copyArm64-v8aDebugAllTableair-frameworkSharedLibraryGdbServer UP-TO-DATE
:app:createArm64-v8aDebugAllTableair-frameworkSharedLibraryGdbsetup
:app:compileArm64-v8aDebugAllTableair-frameworkSharedLibraryTableair-frameworkMainC UP-TO-DATE
:app:linkArm64-v8aDebugAllTableair-frameworkSharedLibrary
/Users/vilius/Software/Android/crystax-ndk-10.2.1/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld:     cannot find -lcrystax
/Users/vilius/Software/Android/crystax-ndk-10.2.1/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld:     cannot find -lcrystax
Error:error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkArm64-v8aDebugAllTableair-frameworkSharedLibrary'.
> A build operation failed.
      Linker failed while linking libtableair-framework.so.
  See the complete log at: file:///Users/vilius/TableAir/Mobile/app/android-studio-project/app/build/tmp/linkArm64-v8aDebugAllTableair-frameworkSharedLibrary/output.txt
```

The .../output.txt displays exactly the same information as in the message window.

Does anyone have ideas about this problem?

Comment: please check the hybrid solution I proposed for *[define LOCAL_SRC_FILES in ndk{} DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636150/define-local-src-files-in-ndk-dsl/32640823#32640823)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, example [here](https://www.crystax.net/en/blog/3) is bit outdated, so we plan to publish new article soon, with updated description of how to use CrystaX NDK with new experimental Gradle plugin. In the meantime, you can look on [example](https://github.com/crystax/android-samples-android-studio) I've pushed to github. The most interesting part of that example is app's build.gradle, so I copy it here for convenience:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

final APP_ABIS = ["armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"]
final BOOST_SHARED_LIBS = ["boost_serialization"]

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "net.crystax.testboost2"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = compileSdkVersion.asType(Integer)
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "test-boost2"
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
        cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
        cppFlags += "-frtti"
        cppFlags += "-Werror"
        cppFlags += "-I" + getBoostIncDir()
        ldLibs.addAll BOOST_SHARED_LIBS
        ldLibs += "log"
        stl = "gnustl_shared"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        APP_ABIS.each { abi ->
            create(getFlavorName(abi)) {
                ndk.with {
                    abiFilters += abi
                    getPrebuiltLibPaths(abi).each { path ->
                        ldFlags += "-L" + path
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

tasks.all {
    task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('link')) {
            task.dependsOn copyNativeLibs, stripNativeLibs
        }
}

task copyNativeLibs {
    ["debug", "release"].each { buildType ->
        APP_ABIS.each { abi ->
            def libs = [:]
            BOOST_SHARED_LIBS.each { name ->
                libs[name] = "${getBoostLibDir(abi)}/lib${name}.so"
            }
            libs.crystax = getLibCrystax(abi)

            libs.each { name, file ->
                dependsOn tasks.create(name: "copy-native-library-${name}-${abi}-${buildType}", type: Copy) {
                    from file
                    into getTargetLibDir(abi, buildType)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task stripNativeLibs(dependsOn: copyNativeLibs) {
    ["debug", "release"].each { buildType ->
        APP_ABIS.each { abi ->
            def libs = []
            libs.addAll(BOOST_SHARED_LIBS)
            libs += "crystax"

            libs.each { name ->
                dependsOn tasks.create(name: "strip-native-library-${name}-${abi}-${buildType}", type: Exec) {
                    commandLine getStripExecutable(abi), "--strip-unneeded", "${getTargetLibDir(abi, buildType)}/lib${name}.so"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}

def getNdkDir() {
    if (System.env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT != null)
        return System.env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT

    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ndkdir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)
    if (ndkdir == null)
        throw new GradleException("""\
                NDK location not found.
                Define location with ndk.dir in the local.properties file
                or with an ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable.""")

    return ndkdir
}

def getCrystaxNdkDir() {
    def ndkDir = getNdkDir()
    if (!(new File(ndkDir, "sources/crystax").exists()))
        throw new GradleException("""\
            '${ndkDir}' is not a CrystaX NDK.
            Edit ndk.dir in local.properties or set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
            environment variable pointing to CrystaX NDK""")

    return ndkDir
}

def getFlavorName(abi) {
    switch (abi) {
        case "armeabi":
            return "arm";
        case "armeabi-v7a":
            return "arm7"
        case "arm64-v8a":
            return "arm64"
        default:
            return abi.replaceAll('-', '_')
    }
}

def getToolchainName(abi) {
    switch (abi) {
        case ~/^armeabi.*/:
            return "arm-linux-androideabi"
        case ~/^arm64.*/:
            return "aarch64-linux-android"
        case "mips":
            return "mipsel-linux-android"
        case "mips64":
            return "mips64el-linux-android"
        case ["x86", "x86_64"]:
            return abi
        default:
            throw new GradleException("Unsupported ABI: '${abi}'")
    }
}

def getToolchainPrefix(abi) {
    switch (abi) {
        case ~/^armeabi.*/:
            return "arm-linux-androideabi"
        case ~/^arm64.*/:
            return "aarch64-linux-android"
        case "mips":
            return "mipsel-linux-android"
        case "mips64":
            return "mips64el-linux-android"
        case "x86":
            return "i686-linux-android"
        case "x86_64":
            return "x86_64-linux-android"
        default:
            throw new GradleException("Unsupported ABI: '${abi}'")
    }
}

def getHostOS() {
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isLinux())
        return "linux"
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX())
        return "darwin"
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows())
        return "windows"
    throw new GradleException("Unsupported host OS")
}

def getHostArch() {
    def arch = System.getProperty("os.arch")
    switch (arch) {
        case ["x86_64", "amd64"]:
            return "x86_64"
        case ~/^i[3456]86/:
        case "x86":
            return "x86"
        default:
            throw new GradleException("Can't detect host's CPU architecture: '${arch}'")
    }
}

def getHostTag() {
    def tag = getHostOS()
    def arch = getHostArch()
    if (tag != "windows" || arch != "x86")
        tag += "-${arch}"
    return tag
}

def getStripExecutable(abi) {
    def ndk = getCrystaxNdkDir()
    def toolchainName = getToolchainName(abi)
    def toolchainPrefix = getToolchainPrefix(abi)
    def hostTag = getHostTag()
    def strip = "${ndk}/toolchains/${toolchainName}-4.9/prebuilt/${hostTag}/bin/${toolchainPrefix}-strip"
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows())
        strip = strip.replaceAll('/', '\\\\') + '.exe'
    return strip
}

def getPrebuiltLibPaths(abi) {
    def paths = []
    paths += getBoostLibDir(abi)
    paths += getLibCrystaxDir(abi)
    return paths
}

def getTargetLibDir(abi, buildType) {
    return "${buildDir}/intermediates/binaries/${buildType}/${getFlavorName(abi)}/lib/${abi}"
}

def getLibCrystaxDir(abi) {
    return "${getCrystaxNdkDir()}/sources/crystax/libs/${abi}"
}

def getLibCrystax(abi) {
    return "${getLibCrystaxDir(abi)}/libcrystax.so"
}

def getBoostDir() {
    return "${getCrystaxNdkDir()}/sources/boost/1.58.0"
}

def getBoostIncDir() {
    return "${getBoostDir()}/include"
}

def getBoostLibDir(abi) {
    return "${getBoostDir()}/libs/${abi}"
}
```

I've tested it with Android Studio 1.4 and gradle experimental plugin 0.2.0.

In fact, custom `copyNativeLibs` task needed only for including shared libraries into apk; if you link with static libraries, `copyNativeLibs` is not needed at all.

**UPDATE:** I've added `stripNativeLibs` task just because I've realized that APK got included unstripped libraries with debug information, making its size too big without any real need in that.

Comment: Don't you need custom **clean** tasks, too, with this approach?

Comment: No, separate **clean** task is not needed, just because the only customization we do here is copying of native shared libraries into `buildDir`, and these `buildDir` is anyway completely removed when executing gradle `:app:clean` task

Comment: It works! Thank you. Just a simple question, how do you explicitly change the build type to x86? It doesn't seem to infer that when building for an emulator.

Comment: Just click menu `Build -> Select Build Variant` and choose `x86Debug` or `x86Release`

Comment: @DmitryMoskalchuk What gradle task should i use to build?

Comment: how to produce an all abi flavor apk? (just like selecting "All" when generating apk)

Answer (score 0):

@dmitry-moskalchuk Hello Dmitry I used your code for the build.gradle and defined the crystax-ndk-10.2.1 within the local.properties as
ndk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-linux/crystax-ndk-10.2.1

I'm always getting the error: 
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> android.compileSdkVersion is missing!

but it is defined within the android section as well as in the androidmanifest.xml

Thank you.