# Android GCC Toolchain Source Code

Tags: android, gcc, toolchain

Is it possible to get the Android NDK GCC toolchain source code? AOSP/NDK already comes with a precompiled toolchain but I'd like to have the source code and compile the toolchain myself to enable some features of GCC not available in the NDK toolchain version.

Comment: May want to look at Crystax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911106/android-studio-14-native-development-crystax-ndk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can find instructions (how to fix and commit something) here:
https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

And toolchains here (GCC,Binutils and etc):
https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/