# gradle experimental include file directories via srcDir srcFile directive

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

Does anyone knows how the includes of srcDir works in gradle experimental files (cpp AND h)? This is kind of a "3-fold" question:

1°) how do the srcDir work?

1.a°) Does it include recursively all subdirs? Does it only include files at their deep level? Does it they include all cpp/c/cc/cxx files?

for example this command:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDir "../../../../some/path/src"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does it include all cpp files under src? all files under src? all cpp files recursively into subdirs? all files recursively into subdirs?

The google documentation is very vague:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

and the gradle one is not clear either:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html

It says it only includes src/${name}/cpp ? what does it mean? Do I have to create a

```
 ../../../../some/path/src/cpp
```

folder?

1.b°) What about the headers:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            exportedHeaders {
                srcDir "../../../../some/path/src"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that the srcDir directive applied on headers works differently than the srcDir for source (it includes only the headers of its current depth)

2°) What if I want a mix between file and dir?

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDir "../../../../some/path/src"
                srcFile "../../../../some/path/src/myFile.cpp" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't seem to work

3°) how does the include/ exclude directive works?

What about the include/exclude directive, does they apply only on the previous srcDir statement? Or do they apply on all the statement of the "source" block?

doing:

```
 android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir "../../../../some/path/src"
                    include "*.cpp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

doesn't seem to include any cpp file. I thought it would include all cpp files of this folder hierarchy, or even all cpp files under src, but it looks like it doesn't.

I want to point that I am using gradle 2.9, which is required by the latest gradle-experimental-0.6.0-alpha3 plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can at least answer my first point. After digging through the sources (at some point it becomes the best documentation), I found the implementation of the methods that retrieves sources:

```
public Set<File> getSrcDirs() {
    Set<File> dirs = new LinkedHashSet<File>();
    for (DirectoryTree tree : getSrcDirTrees()) {
        dirs.add(tree.getDir());
    }
    return dirs;
}
```

in DefaultSourceDirectorySet.java.

this method is used in the gradle-eperimental plugin to retrieve cpp AND c sources:

```
            languageSourceSets.create(
                    sourceSetName + "Cpp",
                    CppSourceSet.class,
                    new Action<CppSourceSet>() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(CppSourceSet source) {
                            source.getSource().setSrcDirs(jni.getSource().getSrcDirs());
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.C");
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.CPP");
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.c++");
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.cc");
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.cp");
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.cpp");
                            source.getSource().include("**/*.cxx");
                            source.getSource().exclude(jni.getSource().getExcludes());
                            source.exportedHeaders(new Action<SourceDirectorySet>() {
                                @Override
                                public void execute(SourceDirectorySet files) {
                                    files.source(jni.getExportedHeaders());
                                }
                            });
                            configurePrebuiltDependency(source, jni);
                        }
                    });
```

in execute method from the NdkConfiguration.java file.

For the header, it's different, there is no such things as 
    source.getSource().include("**/*.H");

, instead we have:

```
            for (LanguageSourceSet sourceSet : nativeBinary.getSources()) {
                if (sourceSet instanceof HeaderExportingSourceSet) {
                    HeaderExportingSourceSet source = (HeaderExportingSourceSet) sourceSet;
                    artifact.getExportedHeaderDirectories().addAll(
                            source.getExportedHeaders().getSrcDirs());
                }
            }
```

In the execute method of the NdkComponentModelPlugin.java. It uses directly the getSrcDirs method of the default gradle implementation, which include recursively all dir under the given one

I will keep on investigating the other points

EDIT: In summary:

1°) 
a°) srcDir includes all file matching the pattern:
    *.C, *.CPP, *.c++, *.cc, *.cp, *.cpp, *.cxx

b°) includeHeaders works, and only include the header at the given folder depth (so you have to give all the subpath to the header if you are including them like this: #include "test.h", instead of #include "dir1/dir2/dir3/test.h"

2°) it looks I was doing some things wrong in my includes, as they now do seem to work. However, you can't just include files. It is thus better to include top dir of source file, and then exclude every file that doesn't match a given pattern (as described in Alex Cohn answer)

3°) The include directive doesn't work

Comment: Nice work! regarding 1b. I was able to verify using exportedHeaders {} results in a -I (include headers) in the options.txt file in the build/tmp/..Arm64.. directory. So I'd say that is precisely what's needed for header file inclusion.

Comment: So how do you specify `headers.srcDir`?

Answer (score 3):

For v. 0.4.0 `srcDirs` includes all subdirectories and `exclude` works on patterns. I don't know about plans to enable `include` or `srcFile`.

```
android.sources {
    main {
       jni.source {
            srcDirs = ["~/srcs/jni"]
            exclude "**/win.cpp"
        }
    }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640823/192373

Even for 0.6.0 the docs don't speak about `exportedHeder`, and generally speaking the gradle native docs are not relevant for Android plugin.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled, it's exportedHeaders. I corrected my post. It is defined here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/c/CSourceSet.html

I am not sure it applies to android plugin, as per your comment, but the android plugin docs are really not up-to-date, and kind of "inherit" gradle default directive (if I understood correctly), so it may work (my test shows that headers are indeed included)

Comment: Also, I am not sure about the srcDirs = ["dir"], as the documentation (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) only mention srcDir "dir" as a way to modify input sources to compile. Could you point me to where you found this directive?

Comment: I am afraid **srcDir** at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental is a mistake. You can find the correct syntax with **srcDirs = […]** [all around Internet](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?#q=jni.source+srcDirs), e.g. the [definitive blog](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/) by [Xavier Hallade](http://ph0b.com/cv-en.html).

Comment: If I read the docs correctly, the developers of Android plugin are "inspired" by the native Gradle plugin, but their development is independent, and the aims are also very different. Some discussions surface at  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev, and if you  ask your questions there, you have a better chance to get an answer directly from the dev. team.

Comment: I've tried all combinations, the only syntax that works is srcDir 'dir'. srcDirs.add(..) and srcDirs = [..] pass gradle sync but don't actually work and are ignored. This is on experimental 0.7.0